# Having several forms and having content inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, forms, insert

I do not have the actual code in front of me but I will try to explain this to the best ability I can.

I have several pages for each province in Canada. Each province page has a very simply HTML form with two fields, artist and song. Basically its for users to post their favorite artist and song. Now, I am using this HTML form on each page for each province.

I am a little bit confused as to how I can make the form work for each province so that content is not inserted into the wrong province page.

Would I need to have a database for each province?

Any help-advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some SQL table structure to see to give us a little perspective here?

Comment: no. you simply keep track of which province you're dealing with and have a field in your data table that says which province the data belongs to. in general, anything that beings with "do I need a database for each XXX" usually can be answered with "no, just have an extra field in ONE table/database to keep track of XXX"

Comment: To add a little technical detail to the comments already posted, one way of doing this would be to have a hidden field on your HTML page, populated with the province (which I assume you can take from the query string/address of the page itself). This field would need to be saved into your database, probably in the same table as the other data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to add a `hidden` field in your form that represents the province, and when inserting in the database simply add this value too, this way you can know which songs / artists came from which province

For British Columbia:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Province" value="BC">
```

For Alberta:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Province" value="AB">
```

etc...

**Edit:**
We would use a hidden variable to pass along data from the `form` to the `php script`. By being hidden, it's a value that the user cannot modify. If you wanted the user to modify it, you would probably use a combo box to choose the Province. That being said, in your script you can now access `$_GET['Province']` which will hold the value set in `HTML`. If you created a different page for every province, you would have to manually set the value accordingly.

I suggest that you have a `Province` field in your database along with the artist / song. When inserting the artist / song in your database, simply add the new field, `Province`. This will now allow you to, for example, `SELECT * WHERE Province='ON'` to fetch all the user input from Ontarians.

Feel free to ask for more clarifications if it's still not clear.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Could you explain to me in a little more detail how setting the input type to hidden could solve this ? Im not a fresh newbie of PHP but i am yet to be a professional at it.....

Comment: Would it be possible to send you a snippet of code and see if im in the right direction ? If yes, could i send it by email ?

Comment: @user1853848 why not, you can easily find my contact info :)